# Not getting all campaign names

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am working on Facebook to fetch Data from Facebook but i am Unable to get all Campaign names in graph api explorer it shows only 25 and there are more than 50 campaigns Please Need Help?

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs, it's all there... You can use the `limit` parameter to define how many result you want to have retrieved, but keep in mind:

> Some edges have an upper maximum on the limit value, for performance reasons. We will return the correct pagination links if that happens.

If you need to use paging to get the next results, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#paging